# Rails def initialize slug explained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization

I am trying to learn Rails and one of the files that I downloaded I can see this:

NOTE: this file is under models.

```
def initialize slug
    api_call "http://yourwebsiteurl.com/REST/" + slug.to_s
end
```

What does this mean? is it like a constructor in Java?

Youssef

Comment: Yes, this is a constructor.

Comment: Is slug a parameter that is passed to the constructor?

Comment: Yes, slug is a parameter passed to the constructor (to `new` method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in the comments, the `initiailze` method is Ruby's new object constructor method. That is, when you call `new` on an object it turns around and calls `initialize`.

But, since you're new to Ruby I'd like to also point out the stylistic issues with the code. The idiomatic Ruby way to write this method would be:

```
def initialize(slug)
  api_call "http://yourwebsiteurl.com/REST/#{slug}"
end
```

The differences being:

1. Always use parentheses around method arguments
2. Always use 2 spaces for indentation
3. Prefer String interpolation (`"#{}"`) over String concatenation (`+`) to insert variables because it's easier and more performant

While these are somewhat arbitrary differences they're still fairly widely accepted. See the [GitHub Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby).

Comment: Thanks dude :), that link is so useful too.

Comment: Hi I got one more question please, what is api_call? is it a variable (no equal sign)?

Comment: `api_call` is a method name. Parentheses are generally optional in ruby method calls. You could also write this bit as `api_call("http://yourwebsiteurl.com/REST/#{slug}")`. In fact, I generally would. My rule on when to use parentheses for method calls is: If you care about the return value of the method call, use parentheses -- otherwise don't. (The reason being that if you care about the result then you may want to chain onto it later, which parentheses allow you to do.) But many in the Ruby community will just only use parentheses when forced to by syntax constraints.